# How do I access Awakening in the Ultimate Edition of Dragon Age: Origins for PS3?

Tags: ps3, dragon-age-origins, dragon-age-origins-awakening

I have the Ultimate Edition of *Dragon Age: Origins* for PlayStation 3, which comes with *Awakening* and all the DLC. I know I'm supposed to access *Awakening* by starting a new game, but it's not showing up.

How can I access it? Is there something else I need to do, or a fix I can apply?

Answer (score 3):

You need to install the DLC and *Awakening* separately: if you just installed the main game, it won't show up. Fernando Melo of BioWare gives [the following solution](http://social.bioware.com/forum/1/topic/68/index/5117062):

> From the XMB, under the game disc icon should be an additional content icon. Selecting that will open another menu which lists each DLC. Select the ones you want and it will install to the PS3 hard drive. When done, go back and select the game disc icon to start the game - the add-on content should now be available.